# Make Console.WriteLine() wrapper work with extra formatting parameters like "{0}"

Tags: c#, static, void

```
public static void Wri(string p)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(20);
    Console.WriteLine(p);
}
```

I made this wrapper method for the command `Console.Writeline()`, to shorten the amount of code it takes up, but i can't use `"{0}"` this way.

How can I pass the parameters that will be formatted into the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the `params object[]` parameter:

```
public static void WriteLineAtPosition(string format, params object[] parameters)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(20);
    Console.WriteLine(format, parameters);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, easy and fast ^^

Answer (score 2):

You need to imitate the original `Console.WriteLine()` method signature:

```
public static void WriteLine(string format, params object[] arg);
```

And in your case:

```
public static void Wri(string p, params object[] arg)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(20);
    Console.WriteLine(p, arg);
}
```

See [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fc0cx9a5(v=vs.110).aspx)